# Is there a way to disable data detectors from Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Is there a way to disable the data detector "feature" from Mail?

[image: Data Detector snapshot]

**LE:** OSX 10.8.3 / Mail 6.3 (1503)

Answer (score 3):

No, Mountain Lion data detectors can not be disabled with a hidden preference (or the preference is so well hidden that nobody has published the details).

Once you know the name, you can search for articles on how to do this in case someone discovers a solution. Sadly, you used to be able to disable these at the terminal on 10.7, but I don't know of a way to disable them on Mountain Lion.

---

If you are on Lion or earlier, try this...

- [Turn off those annoying data detectors in Apple’s Mail](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2008/07/turn-off-those-annoying-data-detectors-in-apples-mail/) by [Jacqui Cheng](http://arstechnica.com/author/jacqui-cheng/) is one such article with the following prescription to clear up the feature.

  1. quit Mail.app
  2. start up Terminal.app
  3. enter the following text exactly

     > defaults write com.apple.mail DisableDataDetectors YES
  4. press return
  5. quit Terminal
  6. open Mail

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I even restarted OSX and they still appear. I checked and i did run the command ok as the value is YES. Daniels-MacBook-Pro:~ daniels$ defaults read com.apple.mail DisableDataDetectors
YES

Comment: Grrr. I haven't tested it on the latest builds. It sure used to be dependable. Why not edit in your version into the question and I'll dig to see if there's any other info on disabling them now.

Comment: Added version. Thank you so much. This "feature" is really really annoying. It would be a life saver to disable this.

Comment: I'm not able to find a quick answer.

Comment: hehe, happens to the best of the best